# How to expand/collapse a specific heading by selecting an option from a ComboBox

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have created a few headings that should stay collapsed until a specific text is selected from a comboxbox dropdown list.

So far I can only find options to expand all for collapse all.

here's what I have... and I'm sure I'm way off base

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()

ComboBox1.List = Array("Tetra Pak T50", "Tetra Pak T100", "Tetra Pak T125")

  If ComboBox1.Value = "Tetra Pak T50" Then
    ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.ExpandAllHeadings
    Else
    ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.CollapseAllHeadings
  End If

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Paragraph.CollapsedState property is used to collapse/expand an individual paragraph. (Note that this is Word 2013 or later - not available in earlier versions.)

Set to False in order to expand a paragraph.

I don't know how you're planning to identify specific paragraphs, but assuming you use a bookmark:

```
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("TetraPak100").Range.Paragraphs(1).CollapsedState = False
```

to expand the paragraph.

Comment: Thanks Cindy, I identified by bookmark and was able to get it to work. Thanks for you help.